Owning child pornography overseas
Bob is a Chinese citizen. Bob bought online children's pornography resources, which only have a one month download deadline. Will he be prosecuted if he goes to the United States again after the download deadline expires.

Owning child pornography is very likely punishable in China as well.

The crime is possession, not access.

In all likelihood, Bob has a problem (beyond the one he should seek therapy for). There is no cloud, there are only other people's servers. And these servers stand somewhere. If Bob is an American resident, likely his cloud provider is storing his files on American servers by default. So Bob uploaded the data from China to the US. In addition, Bob may not be able to clean all temporary files from his computer, so he might have smuggled physical copies into the US as well. What he did was illegal in China, too, but the US won't extradite him.

@littleadv Access can be a form of possession. Possession does not mean simply having something physically in your hands. For example, you are in possession of drugs if they are in a storage locker belonging to you that you have the keys to access.

@ohwilleke right, that's exactly my point. Owning a cloud storage with content is possession.

@littleadv Great, I had misunderstood the point you were making.

Bob is a Chinese citizen. If he cancels his cloud storage account before going to the United States, will he still be sued

@乐乐呵呵狗哥 To be clear, he wouldn't be sued, but he might be criminally prosecuted, in the original question. If all of the child pornography was destroyed in all locations and he retained no possession of it, before leaving China, he probably wouldn't face criminal charges anywhere other than China (where it is presumably still a crime that was committed in China and can be prosecuted there).

In China, having these will not lead to prosecution, production, and dissemination is the only way

These comments are veering into requests for specific legal advice, which is not allowed here.  Please take the tour and read our policies.

@ohwilleke Is it still considered guilty if the key to the safe is destroyed

The content inside was not destroyed, but he was unable to access it. Is he still guilty?

"These comments are veering into requests for specific legal advice."  Really?  How so?  Just curious, because this is an always contentious interpretation, and frankly I don't see it here.

Bob is subject to arrest
new-south-wales
Bob has control of the cloud storage account. Under s91H of the Crimes Act 1900, this is possession within the definition of s308F. If the data contains child abuse material (which child pornography is), then Bob is a criminal the instant he enters NSW jurisdiction not matter where the data is physically located or even if he accesses it while in NSW. The penalty is up to 20 years imprisonment.
AFAIK all Australian states, territories, and the Commonwealth have similar laws.

If his cloud storage resources expire and cannot be accessed. Are you still breaking the law

I assume the setup is as follows: Bob, a Chinese citizen, while located in China downloads child porn on a cloud account with a server located in China. We assume Bob is tech-savvy enough to ensure that data never leaves China (this is fairly non-trivial). This presumably breaks various laws in China and can be prosecuted in China.
Later on Bob travels to the US. By US law he is still in possession of the material, it is in his cloud account and he can access it. So he can be prosecuted.

Isn't there also a law criminalising American citizens that engage in sex crimes overseas? IIRC, it's intended to stop Americans from going overseas to abuse children forced into prositution - wouldn't that law also apply here?

@nick012000 I understood the premise as saying Bob is a Chinese citizen, not an American.
